# variable and function with same name clobbering

Tags: javascript

In the following code:

```
//global scope
function isValid() {
  return "hello from isValid";
}


function test() {
  //local scope
  var isValid = 9;
  //.....
  isValid();
}

test();
```

I get the error:

```
"TypeError: isValid is not a function
    at test (devicok.js:10:5)
    at devicok.js:12:1
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.1.min.js:1:13850
    at https://static.jsbin.com/js/prod/runner-4.1.1.min.js:1:10792"
```

Why is this when as I understand it the isValid function is [in a different scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript) than the isValid variable? It seems that the variable is overriding the function definition. Is the problem that they share the same namespace even though they have different scopes?

[Code and error presented in jsbin.](http://jsbin.com/devicok/edit?js,console)

Comment: When you reference a name, you get the thing with that name in the closest scope. At `isValid();`, the closest scope contains something named `isValid`, so that’s what you get. So yes, they “share the same namespace” in the sense that JavaScript doesn’t have namespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no namespaces in JavaScript - functions and variables and everything live in a single one. Yes, the outer variable is shadowed by the inner declaration - when you refer to `isValid` in the function, it's the local variable. Which has the value `9`, not a function value, and therefore throws an exception when being called.

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
//global scope
function isValid() {
  return "hello from isValid";
}


function test() {
  //local scope
  var isValid = 9;
  //.....
  return this.isValid();
}

console.log(test());
```